# Homotopic maps induce the same cohomology maps?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory

Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces, and let $f,g:X\to Y$ be two continuous maps. Suppose that $f$ and $g$ are homotopic, i.e., there exists a continuous map $H:X\times [0,1]\to Y$ such that $H(x,0)=f(x)$ and $H(x,1)=g(x)$ for all $x\in X$. Prove or disprove that $f^*:H^\ast(Y)\to H^\ast(X)$ and $g^*:H^\ast(Y)\to H^\ast(X)$ are equal as maps between cohomology groups.

Note: Here $H^\ast(X)$ denotes the cohomology groups of $X$, and $f^\ast$ denotes the induced map of $f$ on cohomology.

My try : I know the case when $X$ is a wedge of two circles and $Y$ is the circle. Take $f$ to be the inclusion of one of the circles and $g$ to be the inclusion of the other circle. But don't know how to construct a homotopy $H$ between $f$ and $g$ that induces different maps on cohomology

**Edit:** (copied from comments)

I am familiar with the concept of chain homotopies and how they can be used to prove that homotopic maps induce the same maps on homology. We can construct a chain homotopy between the induced chain maps, which uses the homotopy between the original maps and the singular chain maps.

Comment: Putting aside cohomology for a moment, do you know how to prove that homotopic maps induce the same maps on _homology_? Have you come across the concept of chain homotopies?

Comment: Could you please fix your notation? Your question currently says "$f^:$" and "$H^(Y)$" — the colon and the left parenthesis should not be superscripts. "$f^*$" and "$H^*(Y)$" would be more standard notation.

Comment: @KennyWong Yes, I am familiar with the concept of chain homotopies and how they can be used to prove that homotopic maps induce the same maps on homology . we can construct a chain homotopy between the induced chain maps, which uses the homotopy between the original maps and the singular chain maps.

Comment: The result holds and in Hatcher, the proof is sketched in p.201 of his book. Basically you dualize the argument for homology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're familiar with how chain homotopies are used in homology, I would suggest that the way forward is to use the chain homotopy in homology (which you know exists) to construct something equivalent in cohomology.

Let us remind ourselves of the situation in homology. The continuous maps $f: X \to Y$ and $g: X \to Y$ induce homomorphisms $(f_\#)_n : C_n(X) \to C_n(Y)$ and $(g_\#)_n : C_n(X) \to C_n(Y)$ on the chain groups. Since $f$ and $g$ are homotopic, there exist homomorphisms $P_n : C_n(X) \to C_{n+1}(Y)$ such that
$$ (f_\#)_n - (g_\#)_n = (\partial_Y)_{n+1}\circ P_n  +  P_{n - 1}\circ (\partial_X)_n  \ \ \ \ \ \ (\star),$$
where $(\partial_X)_n : C_n(X) \to C_{n-1}(X)$ and  $(\partial_Y)_n : C_n(Y) \to C_{n-1}(Y)$ are the boundary maps. This $P_\star$ is the *chain homotopy* induced by the homotopy between $f$ and $g$. You're familiar with all of this stuff.

We want to construct something that plays the role of the chain homotopy for *cohomology*. This is done by dualising everything. Note that:

- The cochain groups $C^n(X)$ and $C^n(Y)$ are *by definition* the duals of the chain groups $C_{n}(X)$ and $C_{n}(Y)$.
- The coboundary maps $(\delta_X)^{n} : C^{n}(X) \to C^{n+1}(X)$ and $(\delta_Y)^{n} : C^{n}(Y) \to C^{n+1}(Y)$ are *by definition* the duals of the boundary maps $(\partial_X)^{n+1}$ and $(\partial_Y)^{n+1}$.
- The homomorphisms $(f^\#)^n : C^n(Y) \to C^n(X)$ and $(g^\#)^n : C^n(Y) \to C^n(X)$ induced by $f$ and $g$ on the cochain groups are *by definition* the duals of the homomorphisms $(f_\#)_n$ and $(g_\#)_n$ that they induce on the chain groups.

So it feels very natural to *define* the cochain homotopy maps $Q^n : C^n(Y) \to C^{n-1}(X)$ to be the duals of the chain homotopy maps $P_{n-1}$.

Dualising both side of equation $(\star)$ gives us the equation
$$ (f^\#)^n - (g^\#)^n = Q^{n+1} \circ (\delta_Y)^n + (\delta_X)^{n-1} \circ Q^n \ \ \ \ \ \ (\dagger).$$

Using equation $(\dagger)$, you can prove that if $\alpha \in C^{n}(Y)$ is a cocycle, then $(f^\#)^n (\alpha)$ and $(g^\#)^n (\alpha)$ differ by a coboundary. In other words, you can prove that if $(\delta_Y)^n(\alpha) = 0$, then there exists a $\beta \in C^{n-1}(X)$ such that $(f^\star)^n (\alpha) - (g^\star)^n (\alpha) = (\delta_X)^{n-1}(\beta)$. From here, you can deduce that $f$ and $g$ induce the same maps on cohomology. It's pretty much the same as the argument in homology.

Comment: Thank you i am processing it